# "Dream come true" one word synonym

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that describes 'dream come true'. Any help is greatly appreciated. It can be a feeling and not just a direct translation. Basically, a word that just gets the feeling of a dream coming through. Thanks!

Comment: 'Euphoria' and 'rapture' (feelings of intense joy) are ballpark, if the dream is of a suitable nature.

Comment: Please could you provide an example sentence?  What about 'ideal', 'perfect', etc?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use 'This was/is a dream come true'? That is a perfectly normal idiomatic phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that the dream has already come true, then **fulfillment** is a good word.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what is being asked but, if you were hoping to use "dream come true" a great synonym that I enjoy using is **fantasy**.

i.e.

"This house is my dream come true"

"This is my **fantasy** home"

It fulfills the purpose of replacing the phrase with a single word, while fantasy still maintains that imaginative connotation.

If anything I'd guess fantasized would be more correct, but I still stand by my usage of fantasy. As even though it isn't referring to the verb it as stated it keeps some imaginative juices.

Though if the question is asking for words to describe the feeling of a dream come true then there are plenty options. **Fulfillment**, **euphoric**, **enraptured** etc.

Comment: A fantasy can also be a dream that has no come true.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.  Sources and citations are always encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

This is my dream come true. It is my *Shangri-La*, my *Elysium*, my *Nirvana*.

> Shangri-La = a remote beautiful imaginary place where life approaches perfection
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Shangri-la)

> Elysium = Any place or condition of ideal bliss or complete happiness; paradise
>
> [Your dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/elysium)

> Nirvana = a goal hoped for but apparently unattainable : DREAM
>
> … that nirvana of the … weatherman: A foolproof system of forecasting.
> — Newsweek
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nirvana)

Of these three I prefer *Shangri-La* (despite its hyphenated form) because it is more widely understood than the others.